# Запрос через php и через консоль mysql разный результат

Tags: php, sql, кодировка

Есть такой запрос

```
SELECT `charId` 
        FROM `characters` 
        WHERE `char_name` = 'ааыв' LIMIT 1;
```

Если я его посылаю через Navicat for Mysql консоль - мне выводит результат

А если я через php файл пытаюсь выполнить его, приходит: false;

Я подозреваю что проблемы с кодировкой, но как решить вопрос?...

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name;charset=UTF8";
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $db_user, $db_pass);

$isset_char = "SELECT `charId` 
                FROM `characters` 
                WHERE `char_name` = 'ааыв' LIMIT 1";
$query = $pdo->query($isset_char);

var_dump($query->fetchColumn());//False

// На всякий случай проверяю какой запрос ушел
echo $isset_char;
// SELECT `charId` FROM `characters` WHERE `char_name` = 'ааыв' LIMIT 1
```

Кодировка файла: windows-1251

Если подставить английский ник - то все прекрасно выводит через PDO.

Comment: Перекодируйте файл в utf-8, что бы искомая строка `'ааыв'` соответствовала той что в БД.

Comment: Исправил файл в utf8, не помогло

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте создать подключение с кодировкой которая у вас в таблице БД:

```
 $db = new PDO(
 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=info;charset=utf-8',
 'user',
 'pass',
 array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND=>'SET NAMES utf-8')
);
```

Comment: Вместо query нужно execute для подготовленых запросов. Да и не помогло это.. Оно ведь экранирует..

Comment: @user190134,  а какая кодировка у Вас в таблице characters стоит? Если базе тоже стоит windows-1251, то исправте ваш charset=UTF8 на charset=windows-1251

Comment: в базе utf8, и в колонках тоже